# Out of Office Assistant stopped working on exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

My Out of Office Assistant (OOA) was working before I did some changes on DNS and virtual directories and of which I have forgottten what changes were done. This has now affected my OOA and it is not working. It works from OWA but not through email clients (microsoft outlook). Please need some serious advise.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you have an issue with AutoDiscover or your EWS URL which is causing you these problems.

Use the following cmdlet to change the AutoDicsover URL: `Set-ClientAccessServer –Identity <CAS Server Name> -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri: https://server/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml`

Use this to set the EWS URL: `Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory –Identity "EWS (Default Web Site)" –InternalUrl: https://serverEWS/Exchange.asmx`.
If your IIS Virtual directory is called something different, replace the `-Identity` parameter with the appropriate value (you can determine this by doing `Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl Name, *Url*`).